# Android Studio - How to change resource of an image?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to change resource of an image?

```
        final Switch o = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.obamaswitch);
    if (o.isChecked()){
        o.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView p = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.obamahere);
                p.???;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "change resource of an image"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change image Resource onChecked switch then you can do this

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.obamahere);
   final Switch o = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.obamaswitch);
if (o.isChecked()){
image.setImageResource(R.drawble.icon);
   }
```

and if you want to setImageResource when click on swith then do this

```
new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                   image.setImageResource(R.drawble.icon);
                }else{
                    do your work...
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is a CompoundButton structure?

Comment: @DylanCronkhite - It is the [parent class of CheckBox, RadioButton, Switch, and ToggleButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)

Comment: So, this code will change the resource when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes , When Switch is click then changed

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean setting image programmatically, if yes then you can use setImageResource() property of imageview.
In your case the code will become as

```
p.setImageResource(R.drawable.<yourimagename>)
```

In case you wish to set image from file the you can do as follows

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    p.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Hope this will meet your needs